# Different processing efficiency of same multithread code between linux and windows?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, multithreading

I write a imaging processing program(c++) by using pthread, and it works well under windows(Windows 7, VS2008).

But when I moved these codes to Linux and recompiled(Redhat Enterprise server 6.2, eclipse 3.6.1), the program runs much slower than in windows.

**So, is there any reason for this phenomenon?**

Hardware of two OS is same, they are both nodes of a server, each has 24 cores.

When I run the program in 24 threads, the CPU is about working at 99% on Windows, but on Linux it's about 20%. And on windows the processing will finish in 3 min, while on Linux it's about 30 min.

In my program, I only use pthread_create(), pthread_join() to create multi-thread. I didn't use any locks.

The codes of my program is too much and I can't post it here. If anyone intereste in this issue, you can mail me: chen8729@gmail.com, I will send you the codes.

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: I am not sure but Linux usually uses separate process over separate threads.

Comment: It seems that before kernel version 2.4, Linux separate thread worked as separate process, but after 2.4, it worked as thread.